# Efficient computation of path profile with Numpy and GDAL

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I have numpy array with SRTM elevation data and I need calculate path profiles - vectors with elevation data from one point (transmitter)  to every points of my map. Here's my current solution:

```
def get_elev_vector(self, coord1, coord2, step=90):
    if coord1 == coord2:
        return 0
    lat1, long1 = coord1
    lat2, long2 = coord2
    dist = self.get_dist(coord1, coord2)
    npt = dist / step
    vect = np.zeros(npt + 3, dtype='float32')
    vect[0] = npt
    vect[1] = dist
    vect[2] = self.get_elevation_direct(coord1)
    vect[npt] = self.get_elevation_direct(coord2)
    g = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')
    coordvect = g.npts(long1, lat1, long2, lat2, npt)
    i = 3
    for lon, lat in coordvect:
        vect[i] = self.get_elevation((lat, lon))
        i += 1
    return vect


#(tx, ty) transmission coordinates
while lat > latmax:
         long = longmin
         while long<longmax:
               vect =  self.carta.get_elev_vector((tx, ty), (lat, lon))
               arr[xarr, yarr] = 100
               yarr +=1
               lon += dlon
         xarr +=1
         lat +=dx
```

It works, but it take about 3 hours for 20x20 km area. Is there any way to make it work faster?

Add

```
    def get_elevation(self, coord):
    """TODO"""
    lat, lon = self.xyfromlatlon(coord)
    mlat = int(lat)
    mlon = int(lon)
    vicin = self.tile['numpy_array'][mlat: mlat + 2, mlon: mlon + 2]
    temp_bool = np.equal(vicin, -32768)
    np.putmask(vicin, temp_bool, 0)
    elev = billin_interpol(vicin[0][0], vicin[0][1], vicin[1][0],
                                        vicin[1][1], lat - mlat, lon - mlon)
    return int(elev + 0.5)


def billin_interpol(tl, tr, bl, br, x, y):
"""Bilinear interpolation.
   Return:
    float, interpolated value
"""
b1 = tl
b2 = bl - tl
b3 = tr - tl
b4 = tl - bl - tr + br
return b1 + b2 * x + b3 * y + b4 * x * y
```

[Full code and data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75832939/TEST.rar)

Comment: Please add some sample or fake data so that this is a complete example and indent your code!

Comment: The short answer is probably "yes, use vectorization rather than loops to apply your operations across multiple points", but for the specifics I would want to see some sample input/output data.

Comment: Sorry, this question lacks comments and sample I/O, and the code snippets are incomplete. It's quite impossible to say where you're losing time. You could either go to codereview.stacexchange.com or cut down your problem, profiling some of the function/method calls. (What's the class anyway?)